# what is going on with my trimws?

Tags: r, regex, trim

I was fiddling around in text cleaning when I ran into an interesting occurrence.

Reproducible Code:

```
trimws(list(c("this is an outrante", " hahaha", " ")))
```

Output:

```
[1] "c(\"this is an outrante\", \" hahaha\", \" \")"
```

I've checked out the *trimws* documentation and it doesn't go into any specifics besides the fact that it expects a character vector, and in my case, I've supplied with a list of a list of character vectors. I know I can use *lapply* to easily solve this, but what I want to understand is what is going on with my trimws as is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `trimws` would be directly applied to `vector` and not on a `list`.

According to `?trimws` documentation, the usage is

> trimws(x, which = c("both", "left", "right"))

where

> x- a character vector

It is not clear why the `vector` is wrapped in a `list`

```
trimws(c("this is an outrante", " hahaha", " "))
```

---

If it really needs to be in a `list`, then use one of the functions that goes into the `list` elements and apply the `trimws`

```
lapply(list(c("this is an outrante", " hahaha", " ")), trimws)
```

Also, note that the OP's `list` is a `list` of length 1, which can be converted back to a `vector` either by `[[1]]` or `unlist` (more general)

```
trimws(list(c("this is an outrante", " hahaha", " "))[[1]])
```

---

Regarding why a function behaves this, it is supposed to have an input argument as a `vector`.  The behavior is similar for other functions that expect a `vector`, for e.g.

```
paste(list(c("this is an outrante", " hahaha", " ")))
as.character(list(c("this is an outrante", " hahaha", " ")))
```

---

If we check the `trimws` function, it is calling regex `sub` which requires a `vector`

```
mysub <- function(re, x) sub(re, "", x, perl = TRUE) 
mysub("^[ \t\r\n]+", list(c("this is an outrante", " hahaha", " ")))
#[1] "c(\"this is an outrante\", \" hahaha\", \" \")"
```

Pass it a `vector`

```
mysub("^[ \t\r\n]+", c("this is an outrante", " hahaha", " "))
#[1] "this is an outrante" "hahaha"              ""
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. The last part about calling the sub function is what I was looking for.